# How to fix 'Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False' in the sketch_rnn algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning

I was running the sketch_rnn.ipynb on my jupyter notebook, upon loading the environment to load the trained dataset, it returned an error 'Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False'

This is the code already used by google developers in developing the sketch_rnn algorithm that was even run in the google colab. In the past i have ran it myself on the google colab it worked but seems not to be working on my own jupyter notebook

```
from magenta.models.sketch_rnn.sketch_rnn_train import *
from magenta.models.sketch_rnn.model import *
from magenta.models.sketch_rnn.utils import *
from magenta.models.sketch_rnn.rnn import * 

model_params.batch_size = 1
eval_model_params = sketch_rnn_model.copy_hparams(model_params)
eval_model_params.use_input_dropout = 0
eval_model_params.use_recurrent_dropout = 0
eval_model_params.use_output_dropout = 0
eval_model_params.is_training = 0
sample_model_params = sketch_rnn_model.copy_hparams(eval_model_params)
sample_model_params.max_seq_len = 1
return [model_params, eval_model_params, sample_model_params]


[train_set, valid_set, test_set, hps_model, eval_hps_model, 
sample_hps_model] = load_env_compatible(data_dir, model_dir)
```

i expected the output to be

```
INFO:tensorflow:Downloading http://github.com/hardmaru/sketch-rnn- 
datasets/raw/master/aaron_sheep/aaron_sheep.npz
INFO:tensorflow:Loaded 7400/300/300 from aaron_sheep.npz
INFO:tensorflow:Dataset combined: 8000 (7400/300/300), avg len 125
INFO:tensorflow:model_params.max_seq_len 250.
total images <= max_seq_len is 7400
total images <= max_seq_len is 300
total images <= max_seq_len is 300
INFO:tensorflow:normalizing_scale_factor 18.5198.
```

But it gave me

```
ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False
```

Comment: Same issue here, with the imdb text classification example. Leading to believe that this is on their end with the dataset.

Answer (score 28):

Use allow_pickle=True as one of the arguments to np.load().

Answer (score 22):

This code solved the problem at my side.

```
# Downgrate numpy to fix a problem
!pip install numpy==1.16.2
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
```

I just downgrade numpy as the problem is due to some internal conflict.

Comment: @DuncanJerry You're welcome. you can flag it as the correct answer to help others to find it quickly.

Comment: Changed in version 1.16.3: Made default False in response to CVE-2019-6446. See: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load

Answer (score 12):

So I believe this has just surfaced due to a change in numpy to load(), if you observe the line that the error occurs it references something like

```py
    with np.load(path) as f:
        x_train, labels_train = f['x_train'], f['y_train']
        x_test, labels_test = f['x_test'], f['y_test']
```

but the Keras source code, for example here at line 58: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/datasets/imdb.py

now uses

```py
    with np.load(path, allow_pickle=True) as f:
        x_train, labels_train = f['x_train'], f['y_train']
        x_test, labels_test = f['x_test'], f['y_test']
```

where `np.load(path)` becomes `np.load(path, boolean)`

From brief reading, the addition of `pickles` has to do with security, since `pickles` can contain arbitrary Python code that would be run when something is loaded. (Possibly similar to the way SQL injections are performed)

After updating np.load with the new param list, it's working for my project

Comment: i tried the above code, but it returned [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://github.com/hardmaru/sketch-rnn-datasets/raw/master/aaron_sheep..

Comment: @DuncanJerry, could you add the full error log? I'm guessing the culprit is `load_env_compatible(data_dir, model_dir)`, where the method definition for `load_env_compatible` calls some form of <obj>.load() that needs to be updated.

Comment: ----> 1 with np.load(data_dir, allow_pickle=True) as 
            load_env_compatible:
            2     train_set, test_set, valid_set, hps_model, eval_hps_model, 
            sample_hps_model = load_env_compatible(data_dir, model_dir)     [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://github.com/hardmaru/sketch-rnn-datasets/raw/master/aaron_sheep'

Comment: Numpy 1.16.3 was released few days ago. From release notes: "The functions np.load(), and np.lib.format.read_array() take an
allow_pickle keyword which now defaults to False in response to
CVE-2019-6446 <https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-6446>". Downgrading to 1.16.2 helped me, as the error occurred deep inside some library.