# How to fix error when load dataset in Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, keras

When I'm  load 'reuters' dataset , I get a Error

I try using some :

```
np_load_old = np.load
np.load = lambda *a,**k: np_load_old(*a, allow_pickle=True, **k)
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = reuters.load_data(num_words=10000)
np.load = np_load_old
```

Originally is :

```
from keras.datasets import reuters
import numpy as np
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = reuters.load_data(num_words=10000)
```

> TypeError: () got multiple values for keyword argument
>   'allow_pickle'

Full traceback:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-11-8669b9ae66ea> in <module>()
          1 from keras.datasets import reuters
    ----> 2 (train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = reuters.load_data(num_words=10000)
          3 
          4 

    2 frames
    <ipython-input-2-8333ca7e6c7f> in <lambda>(*a, **k)
          4 
          5 np_load_old = np.load
    ----> 6 np.load = lambda *a,**k: np_load_old(*a, allow_pickle=True, **k)
          7 (train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)
     >     8 np.load = np_load_old

TypeError: <lambda>() got multiple values for keyword argument 'allow_pickle'
```

Comment: Please include the original and complete traceback.

Comment: Why did you override `np.load` with `np.load = lambda *a,**k: np_load_old(*a, allow_pickle=True, **k)`? You get an error because `k` contains `allow_pickle`, which is now a duplicate of `allow_pickle=True`.

Comment: Thanks ForceBru! I'm  deleted (**k)  and it's worked!

Answer (score 6):

so it took me a while to figure this out, but I finally fixed it.
since our problem is the default values of `np.load` then we simply need to change them(temporarily at least).

so before using numpy you can simply add this line to your code:

```
np.load.__defaults__=(None, True, True, 'ASCII')
```

this will change `allow_pickle` to `True`.

then when you're done with what you were doing fix it back

```
np.load.__defaults__=(None, False, True, 'ASCII')
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[Refer this solution](https://trainingsupport.microsoft.com/en-us/tcmpd/forum/all/lab-7-gives-error-typeerror-lambda-got-multiple/38042cb6-a705-4097-a5a7-06771fa02641). This is working for me.

I solved the issue by deleting the `**k` in `old()`. This is because `**k` contains `allow_pickle`. So my command line changed from this:

```py
np.load = lambda *a,**k: old(*a,allow_pickle=True,**k)
```

to this:

```py
np.load = lambda *a,**k: old(*a,allow_pickle=True)
```

Remember to restart your runtime if you have run the command with `**k` in `old()` before you execute the corrected command line.