# nlpnet POSTagger returns error message when allow_pickle=False

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I have installed the latest version of nlpnet library (http://nilc.icmc.usp.br/nlpnet/). Then, when I try to use nlpnet POSTagger according to the follwoing example, I get an error:

```
import nlpnet
tagger = nlpnet.POSTagger('/path/to/pos-model/', language='pt')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/r/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nlpnet/taggers.py", line 205, in __init__
self._load_data()
File "/home/r/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nlpnet/taggers.py", line 423, in _load_data
self.nn = load_network(md)
File "/home/r/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nlpnet/taggers.py", line 38, in load_network
nn = net_class.load_from_file(md.paths[md.network])
File "nlpnet/network.pyx", line 860, in nlpnet.network.Network.load_from_file (nlpnet/network.c:14631)
File "/home/r/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 262, in __getitem__
pickle_kwargs=self.pickle_kwargs)
File "/home/r/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 722, in read_array
raise ValueError("Object arrays cannot be loaded when "
ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False
```

I also tried to install nlpnet again in a different virtual environment, but the error persists. I'm not sure if this is a incompatibility problem, a bug in the lib or an installation issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I am also using nlpnet, and I had the same problem.
Searching on Google, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890813/how-to-fix-object-arrays-cannot-be-loaded-when-allow-pickle-false-for-imdb-loa/56243777) question on Stack Overflow.
Following one of the answers, I downgraded numpy to version 1.16.1, and it worked for me.

```
pip install numpy==1.16.1
```

Hope it helps you.