# Allowing pickle got multiple agruments

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Yesterday I sucessfully loaded the IMDB dataset to my jupyter notebook, with the following code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

# save np.load
np_load_old = np.load

# modify the default parameters of np.load
np.load = lambda *a,**k: np_load_old(*a, allow_pickle=True, **k)

imdb = keras.datasets.imdb

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)

# restore np.load for future normal usage
np.load = np_load_old
```

Now he gives me the error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() got multiple values for keyword argument 'allow_pickle'
```

What do I am missing here?

I am also following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890813/how-to-fix-object-arrays-cannot-be-loaded-when-allow-pickle-false-for-imdb-loa).

Comment: When I restart the kernel it works, why I cannot run this command twice in the same kernel?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all local variable by stopping the kernel "Restart Runtime". It will clear any previously assigned value to "allow_pickle" and solve this problem.