# Face-Recognition: ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, face-recognition, valueerror

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P0ST.png)

```py
def read_array(fp, allow_pickle=False, pickle_kwargs=None):
    version = read_magic(fp)
    _check_version(version)
    shape, fortran_order, dtype = _read_array_header(fp, version)
    if len(shape) == 0:
        count = 1
    else:
        count = numpy.multiply.reduce(shape, dtype=numpy.int64)

    # Now read the actual data.
    if dtype.hasobject:
        # The array contained Python objects. We need to unpickle the data.
        **if not allow_pickle:
            raise ValueError("Object arrays cannot be loaded when "
                             "allow_pickle=False")**
        if pickle_kwargs is None:
            pickle_kwargs = {}
        try:
            array = pickle.load(fp, **pickle_kwargs)
        except UnicodeError as err:
            # Friendlier error message
            raise UnicodeError("Unpickling a python object failed: %r\n"
                               "You may need to pass the encoding= option "
                               "to numpy.load" % (err,))
    else:
        if isfileobj(fp):
            # We can use the fast fromfile() function.
            array = numpy.fromfile(fp, dtype=dtype, count=count)
        else:
            array = numpy.ndarray(count, dtype=dtype)

            if dtype.itemsize > 0:
                # If dtype.itemsize == 0 then there's nothing more to read
                max_read_count = BUFFER_SIZE // min(BUFFER_SIZE, dtype.itemsize)

                for i in range(0, count, max_read_count):
                    read_count = min(max_read_count, count - i)
                    read_size = int(read_count * dtype.itemsize)
                    data = _read_bytes(fp, read_size, "array data")
                    array[i:i+read_count] = numpy.frombuffer(data, dtype=dtype,
                                                             count=read_count)

        if fortran_order:
            array.shape = shape[::-1]
            array = array.transpose()
        else:
            array.shape = shape

    return array
```

Comment: What is being passed to the function?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read this first:

[How to fix 'Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890813/how-to-fix-object-arrays-cannot-be-loaded-when-allow-pickle-false-for-imdb-loa)