# Allow_Pickle = True modified my dictionary to "unsized" when loaded

Tags: python

I am trying to save and load variables (dictionaries) to use in other notebooks. I save the variables with:

```
with open('opp2b.npy', 'wb') as f:
    np.save(f, mak)
    np.save(f, mp)
    
len(mak)
82
```

mak and mp are dictionaries with 82 entries of the same length.
When loading if not using allow_pickle = True it will not load. So I use this

```
with open('opp2b.npy', 'rb') as f:
    mak = np.load(f, allow_pickle=True)
    mp = np.load(f, allow_pickle=True)
```

and when I check the length I get

```
len(mak)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-bb967ce1f5ef> in <module>
----> 1 len(mak)

TypeError: len() of unsized object

1
```

I am not sure why the array is modified, but it is now unusable for what I need it.

Comment: What does "it will not load" mean?

Comment: Basically this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890813/how-to-fix-object-arrays-cannot-be-loaded-when-allow-pickle-false-for-imdb-loa

Comment: What are `mak` and `mp`?

Comment: A dictionary of length 82 and the entries are arrays of the same length (51). the entries are called by numbers. i.e  len(mak[4]) = 51

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75313518/allow-pickle-true-modified-my-array-to-unsized-when-loaded#comment132894291_75313518), `mak` is not a `numpy` array at all. [`numpy.save` is specifically documented](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) to:

> Save an array to a binary file in NumPy `.npy` format.

`allow_pickle` is for `numpy` arrays containing Python objects, but the `.npy` format is not intended to store things that aren't `numpy` arrays at all. To successfully store the `dict`, it's wrapping it in a 0D `numpy` "array", and that's what `np.load` is giving you. You could extract the original `dict` by doing:

```
mak = mak.item(0)  # mak = mak[0] doesn't work, and I'm unclear on why .item(0) works,
                   # as the docs claim the only difference is that .item(0) returns
                   # a Python scalar, rather than a numpy scalar, and that's not an
                   # issue here, but I assume something about 0D arrays requires this
```

But really, that's trying to put a square peg in a round hole. If you're not storing `numpy` arrays, there's little benefit to the `.npy` format, if any. The main advantages it provides are:

1. Avoiding arbitrary code execution for untrusted inputs (since you need to `allow_pickle`, that advantage goes away)
2. Allowing you to memory map on load (irrelevant when the *entire* data structure must be pickled anyway; memory mapping helps only for C level data where you might benefit from lazy loading and better performance if RAM grows short, as the data need not be written to swap before the pages are reclaimed)
3. (No longer relevant on modern Python) Stores array data more efficiently than the old `pickle` protocol `0` (that produced legal ASCII output, meaning only bytes of 127 or below, which made pickling raw binary data inefficient). As long as you're using protocol 2 or higher (which is binary, handles new-style classes efficiently, and is supported back to Python 2.3), it should store your data efficiently. As of Python 3.0, the *default* protocol is protocol 3 (rising to protocol 4 in 3.8), so if you're using a supported version of Python, and don't specify the protocol, it will use 3 or 4 (both of which work fine; protocol 4 being better if you're pickling *huge* objects).

Since you aren't storing `numpy` arrays, just rely on the `pickle` module directly to store *arbitrary* data (for modern pickle protocols, which allow efficient binary storage, `numpy` stores efficiently enough anyway, so the `.npy` format isn't helping much, if at all; for some trivial test cases I tried, saving `{'a': numpy.array([0,1,2])}`, the `.npy` dump was over twice the size).

```
import pickle  # At top of file

with open('opp2b.pkl', 'wb') as f:  # Name with common pickle extension instead of .npy
    pickle.dump(mak, f)  # Argument order reversed from np.save
    pickle.dump(mp, f)
```

and then to load:

```
with open('opp2b.pkl', 'rb') as f:  # Matching change in name
    mak = pickle.load(f)
    mp = pickle.load(f)
```

This assumes you might in fact want to load only one data set or the other at a time; if you plan to store and load both all the time, you may as well condense it to a single write of a `tuple` of the relevant values (increasing the chance that duplicated objects across the two objects can use back-references to avoid reserializing the same data multiple times), e.g.:

```
with open('opp2b.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump((mak, mp), f)
```

and:

```
with open('opp2b.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    mak, mp = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: As a side-note: Officially, [`.npy` is only for *single* arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html#module-numpy.lib.format), with `.npz` files being for *multiple* arrays, so you were already lightly violating the rules for `.npy` (that said, it probably works just fine the way you've done it, so long as you don't try to use the memory mapping facilities which won't realize you'd got two "arrays" stored back-to-back).